# How to make the second frame inside the Main?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have this simple `JFrame` the classname is `MainFrame` here is the screenshot

[image]

I want to do some `MDI` thing.

for now, I only know this

```
private void mhsaddshowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    addMhs AM = new addMhs();
    AM.setVisible(true);  
    //desktopPane.add(AM);
}
```

and with my script above now i have two separated window.

[image]

so how can i make the second window (`addMhs();`) as the child and MainFrame  as the parent ?

I'm new with this, maybe you can share a tutorial link about my problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

in order to make MDI app with java you have to use DesktopPane and add JInternalFrame inside your DesktopPane.

Answer (score 1):

Frames will have a separate window.

You should use [Panel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) instead.

You can show a panel inside `JFrame`. Read [how to use panel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Comment: there is a comment from joy. It may out of topic. Which one is the better solution, yours or joy's ? sorry bad english